# Angularjs 2 directives from different libs same name

Tags: angularjs

How can I pick the right directive **without** modifying either lib code?

Is angular allowing to set prefix for directives from library on import?
Is there angular syntax for embedding module name in directive name?

Comment: if you're only integrating them with the <script> tag I don't think you will be able to do this. One idea could be to create a directive "parentDirective" which injects the correct library directive based on the route you're calling the directive

Comment: Not just with <script> but I'm relaying on bower dependencies, and would not care to set up my own bower repo for just one liners...

Comment: Well, I think the easiest thing if the libraries are both just the same directive is to do it by hand. There is, as far as I know, no possibility to just get all Directives and change their name, as angular relies heavily on their DI. I would say, the lib developers had to use more proper names.